# Gradle Removing Comments from Library Build

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to provide documentation for my library. I've tried every way possible - comments, `@Name`, `@Description` and `@JavaBean`. None of them work (as seen in Image 3)

It seems as when I compile my library with Gradle (`gradlew build`), it removes the comments. Is there a way to prevent this?

Of course you need 10 rep to post images and probably links too but I tried.

Decompiled source code (from IntelliJ IDEa)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqIJy.png

Actual source code (before compiled)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJtQY.png

What the "Event" class looks like when hovered over.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STDc6.png

Gradle, what I'm suspecting is the problem, doesn't remove the name, description or javabean annotations but it does remove the comments. Any help?

Comment: It's unclear where you're expecting the comments to _go_. Generally, for an open-source library, you upload _three separate_ jars: one with `.class` files, one with source code, and one that's a ZIP of your processed Javadoc comments.

Comment: An example set of artifacts for JUnit at Maven Central: [binaries](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.2.jar), [javadocs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.2-javadoc.jar), [sources](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.2-sources.jar). Usually pushing the sources jar along your binaries to a repository will make most of the IDEs use these sources when the user navigates to your library's code.

Comment: It's just that your IDE resorts to the decompiled sources (where the comments are optimized-out) because it cannot find a sources jar for your code.

Comment: @jannis How do I compile the sources jar then? I can find no documentation about how to do this with Gradle.

Comment: How and where you publish your library? How do you use it?

Comment: Here is the source of my Maven repository where I release my builds: https://github.com/BeriiDevelopment/mvn. Here is also my library which I want to compile with comments: https://github.com/BeriiDevelopment/BES. I use `gradlew build `to build my library, `mvn install` to publish it, and import the library via `build.gradle`.

Comment: @acaiberii Gradle to build the library and Maven to publish it? Why?

Comment: It's in two different directories, and if the build.gradle source is public idk what to do.